# How do I use an email link to execute a macro with the message's body used as parameters?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wrote an Excel VBA macro that used a userform to send a form email to an internal manager for approval. I want to write a complimentary macro the same manager can use to relay this information to a different set of internal recipients. The problem I'm trying to wrap my head around is how can I have the manager click an embedded link to another (different) Excel worksheet that would, upon opening, populate the new userform with the information from the email?

To make this idea more clear, the userform collects 5 pieces of information:

MPL(master price list) serial number, Effective date, Manager's name, Impact (yes/no), User's name (derived from application.username)

This information gets emailed to the manager for approval, with a link embedded to another macro enabled workbook on the server where the manager can compose another email using a userform with the same information plus extra account-specific information. The problem I'm trying to solve is how can I take the email body's contents as parameters when the second macro/workbook is opened (so I can auto-fill the second userform).

Let me make this clear: I DO NOT WANT CODE WRITTEN FOR ME! I just want an answer to a conceptual question. Can this even be done? Is there a better way to execute this I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

JSR

Answer (score 0):

Using the Outlook object model you can access any mail item using its `EntryID` and its `StoreID`

```
Dim EntryID As String
Dim StoreID As Variant
Dim mi As Outlook.mailItem

... 
Set mi = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryID, StoreID)
```

Provided, you write die `EntryID/StoreID` into an `Excel` sheet, you could access the mail from `Excel VBA` and analyze its contents.

It might be easier to define a rule for incoming mails in your manager's `Outlook` to automatically process your form mails, extract their contents and prepare an approval.